# Faster reading of inbox in Java

Tags: imap, pop3, gmail-imap, jakarta-mail

I'd like to get a list of everyone who's ever been included on any message in my inbox.  Right now I can use the javax mail API to connect via IMAP and download the messages:

```
Folder folder = imapSslStore.getFolder("[Gmail]/All Mail");
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();

for(int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  // This causes the message to be lazily loaded and is slow
  String[] from = messages[i].getFrom();
}
```

The line messages[i].getFrom() is slower than I'd like because is causes the message to be lazily loaded.  Is there anything I can do to speed this up?  E.g. is there some kind of bulk loading I can do instead of loading the messages one-by-one?  Does this load the whole message and is there something I can do to only load the to/from/cc fields or headers instead?  Would POP be any faster than IMAP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [fetch](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Folder.html#fetch%28javax.mail.Message%5B%5D,%20javax.mail.FetchProfile%29)-method in Folder. According Javadocs:

> Clients use this method to indicate that the specified items are
>   needed en-masse for the given message range. Implementations are
>   expected to retrieve these items for the given message range in a
>   efficient manner. Note that this method is just a hint to the
>   implementation to prefetch the desired items.

For fetching FROM appropriate FetchProfile is [ENVELOPE](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/FetchProfile.Item.html#ENVELOPE). Of course it is still up to implementation and mail server does that really help.

Answer (score 6):

You want to add the following before the for loop

```
FetchProfile fetchProfile = new FetchProfile();
fetchProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
folder.fetch(messages, fetchProfile);
```

This will prefetch the "envelope" for all the messages, which includes the from/to/subject/cc fields.